# Translating Matlab scrambler function to C

Tags: c++, c, matlab, simulink, translate

I am trying to implement the following matlab function in c:
[Mathworks scrambler Function Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.scrambler-system-object.html)

This is the code I've written:

```
#define N 5
#define MAX 70
#define BITS 7
//char* msg = "This message is Coming to You!";
//char* msg = "Hello world 000\nHello world 001\nHello world 002\nHello world 003\n";
//char* msg = "Hello world 000\nHello world 001\n";
char* msg = "Hel";

uint8_t current[N-1] = {0};
uint8_t to_Xor[N-1] = {0};

uint8_t bin[MAX*BITS];

int main()
{
    int len=strlen(msg);
    int kk = 0;
    int m = 0;
    uint8_t letter = 0;
    uint8_t chars = 0;


    for(int nn = 0; nn < len*BITS; nn++)
    {
        bin[nn] = 0;
    }

    for(int ii = 0; ii < len; ii++)
    {
        letter = msg[ii];
        for(int jj = 6; jj>=0; jj--)
        {
            bin[kk]=(letter&(1<<jj))>>jj;
            //printf("%d\n",bin[k]);
            kk++;
        }

    }

    uint8_t xor = 0;
    uint8_t polynom = 0x0;
    uint8_t scrmbld_output[len*BITS];

    for(int c = 0; c < len*BITS; c++)
    {
        scrmbld_output[c] = 0;
    }


    for(int bin_ndx = 0; bin_ndx < len*BITS; bin_ndx++)
    {

        for(int n = 0; n < N-1; n++)
        {
            if((1<<n)&polynom)
            {
                xor ^= current[n];
            }
        }

        for (int k = N-2; k > 0; k--)
        {
            current[k]=current[k-1];
        }

        current[0] = xor ^ bin[bin_ndx] ^ 1;

        scrmbld_output[bin_ndx] = current[0];
        xor = 0;

        printf("original: %d scrmbld: %d\n",bin[bin_ndx], scrmbld_output[bin_ndx]);
    }

    int k = 0;
    m = 6;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 6; j>=0; j--)
        {
            chars |= bin[k]<<m;
            k++;
            m--;
        }
        printf("%c", chars);
        chars = 0;
        m = 6;
    }

    printf("\nlen: %d", len);
    return 0;
}
```

The results I get from matlab are different.

If I create the following vector and scrambler in matlab:

```
a = [ 1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0 ];
scrmblr = comm.Scrambler(2,[1 1 1 0 1], [0 0 0 0]);
ans = scrmblr(a');
ans' = [1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1]
```

but what I'm getting is:

```
original: 1 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 1
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 1 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 1
original: 1 scrmbld: 1
original: 1 scrmbld: 1
original: 0 scrmbld: 1
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 1 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 1
original: 1 scrmbld: 0
original: 1 scrmbld: 0
original: 1 scrmbld: 1
original: 0 scrmbld: 1
original: 1 scrmbld: 1
original: 1 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 1
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
original: 0 scrmbld: 0
```

I don't see where I went wrong. Any help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In `scrmblr = comm.Scrambler(2,[1 1 1 0 1], [0 0 0 0]);` shouldn't polynomial and condition vector be the same size?

Comment: No. Initial condition vector must be 1 smaller than polynomial vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
Your C code is may be a little complicated and can be simplified.

Note that you've made some mistakes:

- `polynom` was not set
- in `current[0] = xor ^ bin[bin_ndx] ^ 1`, `^1` has no reason to be.

---

I reworked the code to be more comprehensible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N 5

uint8_t bin[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
uint8_t state[N-1] = {0};

int main()
{
    int len=sizeof bin;      
    uint8_t state [N-1] = {0,0,0,0};

    /* looking at documentation, the first element in poly is ignored... */
    uint8_t poly [N-1] = {1,1,0,1};

    for(int bin_ndx = 0; bin_ndx < len; bin_ndx++)
    {
        uint8_t xor = 0;
        for(int n = 0; n < N-1; n++)
        {
            if(poly[n])
            {
                xor ^= state[n];
            }
        }

        for (int k = N-2; k > 0; k--)
        {
            state[k]=state[k-1];
        }

        state[0] = xor ^ bin[bin_ndx] ;

        printf("input: %d, output: %d, state: %d %d %d %d %d\n", bin[bin_ndx],
            state[0], state[0], state[1], state[2], state[3], state[4]);

    }     
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I removed the hex to bin part which was not revelant.

Before re-adding it, I suggess you to separate your code into functions, one for scrambling, one for conversion, and so...

For instance:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* Binary scramble
   input: array of size *size* to be processed 
   output: array to store the result, must be as big as input 
   poly: polynom to use: array of *order* size
   state: internal state: array of *order* size
   order: order of polynom       
   */
void scramble (uint8_t *input, uint8_t *output,size_t size, uint8_t *poly, uint8_t *state, size_t order)
{    
    /* ignore the order 0 */
    poly++;
    state++;
    order--;

    /* for each input bits */
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /* compute the value to be xored to input */
        uint8_t xor = 0;
        for(int n = 0; n < order; n++)
        {
            if(poly[n])
            {
                xor ^= state[n];
            }
        }

        /* shift the state */
        for (int k = order-1; k > 0; k--)
        {
            state[k] = state[k-1];
        }

        /* compute the ouput */ 
        output[i] = state[0] = xor ^ input[i] ;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t bin[10] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    uint8_t out[10];
    uint8_t poly[5] = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    uint8_t state[5] = {0};

    scramble(bin, out, 10, poly, state, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", bin[i], out[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I apologize, didn't notice `polynom` was zero. It was supposed to be `0xb`
Thank you!